GIRA Homeserver using xxAPI2 (Javascript issue)
I use a GIRA Homeserver for home automation.
To expand the visual presentation I use the xxAPI2 library, full "plug-in" can be found on Github.
One of the visual controls used by xxAPI2 is the NoUiSlider from refreshless.com
in the present xxapi2 version (2.044) the NOuislider version 7.xx is in use.
I'm working on an update to 15.x of the nouislider.
In the time from 7.xx to 15.xx the create call has been changed.
I Think under the hood some more ...
Anyway I use the new call.
for example:
oarg.item.xxapi.slider = document.getElementById(oarg.item.uid);
noUiSlider.create(oarg.item.xxapi.slider, oarg.item.xxapi.slider_options);

Everything works fine so far, I can jump back and forward between pages etc.
But when I push the refresh button. Thinks go wrong....
When I want to display the slider again, the element can not be found.
I build in a test to check if the DOM is ready, even then getelementbyid returns null.
Even a time-delay of 5 second (should be enough to load) does not solve the problem.
When I close the tab, and open it again it is still not working, flushing the browser and start again, then everything is fine again....
Any ideas on how to solve this problem.
Regards,
G.
